# Unable to get stat with dlsym

Tags: c, shared-libraries, dlopen, dlsym

I'm trying to write a hook for `stat`/`lstat`/`fstat` but I can't seem to get the original version from `dlsym`. I'm using the following code to obtain the original pointers.

```
orig_stat = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "stat");
orig_lstat = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "lstat");
orig_fstat = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fstat");
```

However, all three variables are set to `null` and calling `dlerror` also returns `null`.

I'm creating the shared object with:

```
clang fakestat.c -shared -fPIC -ldl -o fakestat.so
```

and using my library by running a test program with `LD_PRELOAD=fakestat.so ./test`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `stat` family functions are actually wrappers to internal functions in glibc. You can look at the output of `objdump` on your binary that calls any of the standard `[lf]stat` calls and you'll see the actual symbols in the binary for these functions. So you'll have to hook those functions. The following are the functions you want to hook/`dlsym` on:

`__xstat` & `__xstat64` for `stat`.

`__lxstat` & `__lxstat64` for `lstat`.

`__fxstat` & `__fxstat64` for `fstat`.

The `64` suffixed functions are for [LFS support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_file_support). See the [feature test macros.](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html)