# __xstat dynamic symbol resolving error on 64bit

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I am trying to dynamically load stat function using dlopen and dlsym.
Functions from stat family are wrapped in corresponding functions `__xstat`, `__xstat64` itp.

Following sniped of code, compiles and works when compiled in 32bit mode (`sys/stat.h` is included to get stat structure for sake of example)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

typedef int (*xstat_f) (int __ver, const char *__filename, struct stat *__stat_buf);

int main()
{
    auto* h = dlopen("libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!h)
    {
        return 1; // invalid handle
    }

    auto f = (xstat_f)dlsym(h, "__xstat");
    if(!f)
    {
        return 1; // invalid handle
    }

    struct stat s = {};

    const auto r = f(3, "/tmp", &s);

    if (r != 0)
    {
        perror("stat");
        return errno;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`g++ main.cpp -o main -ldl -m32`

Executable compiled without `-m32` switch on 64bit machine returns EINVAL (Invalid argument).

What is the reason?

Also I've made a minimal test

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(){
    struct stat s;
    const auto x = stat("/tmp", &s);
    if(x != 0) return errno;
    return 0;
}
```

and using `objdump -T`, on both executables, 32bits and 64bits, shows that `stat` is resolved as `__xstat`, so I am using correct symbol. Also I've tried combination of `__xstat/__xstat64`, `struct stat/stat64`, same result.

Comment: Instead of `perror` use `dlerror`. Also you shouldn't try to use undocumented/platform-specific functions.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I agree that these are not intended as user functions, but they **are** documented as standard system interface functions: https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_2.0.1/LSB-generic/LSB-generic.txt

Comment: According to this accepted answer, It's the symbol to resolve stat function
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994135/unable-to-get-stat-with-dlsym/48994371#48994371

Comment: You can call these methods directly, though you need to add the version first parameter as `_STAT_VER`. Try calling that directly from main()

Comment: In my specific case, it must be done through dlopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

__xstat declarations follows:

```
int __xstat(int ver, const char *path, (struct stat *stat_buf))
```

in documentation parameter ver is described like, `ver shall be 3 or the behavior of these functions is undefined`, which is not entirely true, because in source code, definition of `_STAT_VER_LINUX` follows:

```
#ifndef __x86_64__
# define _STAT_VER_LINUX    3
#else
# define _STAT_VER_LINUX    1
#endif
```

That's why `__xstat` call on 64bits was failling, parameter `ver` should have been set to 1, and 3 on 32bits compilation.